# How to add a line break when using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I am wondering how to add a line break for each element when using XmlSerializer?

Sample code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xxx));
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml")
{
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, xxx);
}
```

Comment: Why? A computer does not care about line breaks.

Comment: @leppie: However, a human might. That's the only reason for using XML anyways - otherwise you could just use binary data.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When creating the `XmlWriter`, pass in an [`XmlWriterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) object with `Indent` set to `true`.

```
var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xxx));
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml", xmlWriterSettings)
{
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, xxx);
}
```

Comment: Or if using XmlTextWriter, set "obj.Formatting = Formatting.Indented" after construction

Answer (score 6):

You can use XmlWriterSettings and set the properties to out the indentation and newlines. .Indent and .NewLineOnAttributes seem to be what you would want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx