# How to properly xml serialize (with the correct schema)

Tags: c#, xml, schema, xmlserializer

I have a class that I deserialize with:

```
 public static bool FileDeserializer<T>(string xmlFileName, out T element, out string strError)
 {
  try
  {
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(xmlFileName))
    { element = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader); }
    strError = string.Empty;
    return true;
 }
 catch (Exception exc)
 {
  strError = "XmlFileDeserializer exception: " + exc;
  element = default(T);
  return false;
 }
```

}

and serialize with

```
public static bool FileSerializer<T>(T value, string strFilename, out string strError)
{
    try
    {
          var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
          using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(strFilename))
          { serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value); }
          strError = string.Empty;
          return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
      strError = "XmlFileSerializer exception: " + exc;
      return false;
    }
 }
```

Now everything works fine with serialize/deserialize.
But when I try to read it to modify it:

- with visual studio it's on a single line (so very hard to read)
- with an other editor (xml explorer) i get the message:

> The document does not have a specified schema. Click to apply one.

So I have searched for [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) but didn't understand how to put that in my code.

Thanks

---ADD---
Here is the xml in question sorry for not having added it before

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><CfgData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><DialogFileIniDir>C:\temp</DialogFileIniDir><HorSplitterPos>204</HorSplitterPos><VerSplitterPos>358</VerSplitterPos><GridStep>10</GridStep><Scale>0</Scale><TraceThickness>3</TraceThickness><ShadowsEnabled>false</ShadowsEnabled><Theme>LIGHT</Theme><LightForeground><A>255</A><R>0</R><G>0</G><B>0</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0</ScR><ScG>0</ScG><ScB>0</ScB></LightForeground><LightBackgound><A>255</A><R>245</R><G>245</G><B>245</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0.913098633</ScR><ScG>0.913098633</ScG><ScB>0.913098633</ScB></LightBackgound><LightTraceOkColor><A>255</A><R>255</R><G>255</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>1</ScR><ScG>1</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></LightTraceOkColor><LightTraceCancelColor><A>255</A><R>255</R><G>0</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>1</ScR><ScG>0</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></LightTraceCancelColor><LightTraceEndColor><A>255</A><R>0</R><G>0</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0</ScR><ScG>0</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></LightTraceEndColor><LightHeaderUnselectedBG><A>255</A><R>0</R><G>206</G><B>209</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0</ScR><ScG>0.6172066</ScG><ScB>0.637596846</ScB></LightHeaderUnselectedBG><LightHeaderSelectedBG><A>255</A><R>0</R><G>0</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0</ScR><ScG>0</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></LightHeaderSelectedBG><LightHeaderStartEndBG><A>255</A><R>105</R><G>105</G><B>105</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0.141263291</ScR><ScG>0.141263291</ScG><ScB>0.141263291</ScB></LightHeaderStartEndBG><LightHeaderFG><A>255</A><R>255</R><G>255</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>1</ScR><ScG>1</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></LightHeaderFG><LightBlockBG><A>255</A><R>220</R><G>220</G><B>220</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0.7156935</ScR><ScG>0.7156935</ScG><ScB>0.7156935</ScB></LightBlockBG><LightBlockFG><A>255</A><R>255</R><G>255</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>1</ScR><ScG>1</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></LightBlockFG><DarkForeground><A>255</A><R>255</R><G>255</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>1</ScR><ScG>1</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></DarkForeground><DarkBackgound><A>255</A><R>19</R><G>56</G><B>53</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0.00651209056</ScR><ScG>0.0395462364</ScG><ScB>0.0356013142</ScB></DarkBackgound><DarkTraceOkColor><A>255</A><R>255</R><G>255</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>1</ScR><ScG>1</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></DarkTraceOkColor><DarkTraceCancelColor><A>255</A><R>255</R><G>0</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>1</ScR><ScG>0</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></DarkTraceCancelColor><DarkTraceEndColor><A>255</A><R>0</R><G>0</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0</ScR><ScG>0</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></DarkTraceEndColor><DarkHeaderUnselectedBG><A>255</A><R>220</R><G>220</G><B>220</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0.7156935</ScR><ScG>0.7156935</ScG><ScB>0.7156935</ScB></DarkHeaderUnselectedBG><DarkHeaderSelectedBG><A>255</A><R>0</R><G>0</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0</ScR><ScG>0</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></DarkHeaderSelectedBG><DarkHeaderStartEndBG><A>255</A><R>105</R><G>105</G><B>105</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0.141263291</ScR><ScG>0.141263291</ScG><ScB>0.141263291</ScB></DarkHeaderStartEndBG><DarkHeaderFG><A>255</A><R>255</R><G>255</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>1</ScR><ScG>1</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></DarkHeaderFG><DarkBlockBG><A>255</A><R>220</R><G>220</G><B>220</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>0.7156935</ScR><ScG>0.7156935</ScG><ScB>0.7156935</ScB></DarkBlockBG><DarkBlockFG><A>255</A><R>255</R><G>255</G><B>255</B><ScA>1</ScA><ScR>1</ScR><ScG>1</ScG><ScB>1</ScB></DarkBlockFG></CfgData>
```

Comment: You can have a correct xml string on a single line. What you are looking for is a XML formatter. You can find one here : http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html

Comment: Thanks that's useful. That said the problem with the schema remains

Comment: Could you please share your XML string ?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Please see my edit

Comment: To indent while serializing see [How to add a line break when using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4363886/3744182).