# How to add a line break after each attribute when serializing xaml document using XamlServices.Save()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization

I want to add a line break for each attribute for readability reasons when serializing xaml document.

The class I want to serialize looks like:

```
namespace XMLTest
{
    [Serializable]
    public class FHConfig
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "Configuration";
        public string SettingA { get; set; } = "SettingA";
        public string SettingB { get; set; } = "SettingB";
        public string SettingC { get; set; } = "SettingC";
        public FHConfig() { }
    }
}
```

I use this code to save object as xaml file:

```
try
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "config.xml");
    using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        FHConfig obj = new FHConfig();
        XamlServices.Save(writer, obj);

    }
}
catch (Exception exep) { MessageBox.Show("Saving UI parameters: " + exep.Message); }
```

It produces the file where each tag is in one text line:

```
<FHConfig Name="Configuration" SettingA="SettingA" SettingB="SettingB" SettingC="SettingC" xmlns="clr-namespace:XMLTest;assembly=XMLTest" />
```

But I want serializer to insert line breaks after each attribute. I know there is similar question [How to add a line break when using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363886/how-to-add-a-line-break-when-using-xmlserializer), but it addresses the same issue in xml documents.

`XamlServices.Save()` can use `XamlWriter`, but there is no clue on how to format output text in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use method `XamlServices.Save Method (XmlWriter, Object)` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd292727(v=vs.110).aspx)) and set property `NewLineOnAttributes` of `XmlWriterSettings` class to `true`:

```
try
{
    var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, NewLineOnAttributes = true };
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "config.xml");
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(path, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        FHConfig obj = new FHConfig();
        XamlServices.Save(xmlWriter, obj);
    }
}
catch (Exception exep) { MessageBox.Show("Saving UI parameters: " + exep.Message); }
```

If you want to omit XML declaration from file "`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`" you should set `OmitXmlDeclaration` to `true`.

Comment: For some reson, attributes with a namespace, such as `x:Key` become an internal tag inside the element.